# why is that question locked - it's active, people try to share their findings and the question is not answered yet

Tags: support

[illegitimate traffic from user agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.10) Gecko/2009042316 Firefox/3.0.10 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)](https://serverfault.com/questions/370378/illegitimate-traffic-from-user-agent-mozilla-5-0-windows-u-windows-nt-5-1-en?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 4):

My guess is because all it was getting was "Me too!" answers, which are not really helpful. The vast majority of them should have been comments. There's also been a lot of less than helpful content that's since been deleted as well.

The unfortunate fact is that this is not a good site for "sharing findings". It's a great site for getting an answer, but findings means discussions and discussions means mess on a system like Server Fault, which leads to a useless Q/A because what's possibly the correct answer gets lost in all the assumptions and findings.

Comment: I'm doing my best to clean it up but I have to go to work now, I'll pick it up later today if I can.

Comment: Ok, it's all cleaned up. Let's see if it stays this way.

Comment: That "question" is such a mess, even after your cleanup, that I don't believe it serves any useful purpose at all. It just attracts a lot of people who haven't bothered to read the FAQ.

Comment: Vote to close, anyone?

Comment: I think it should be kept open. If an answer is found, it could be valuable.

Comment: If an answer is found it will be lost amongst all that crap and would therefore be worthless.

Comment: I'll protect the question to try and cut down the "I found this on google and, me too" stuff so that Mark's tidy up doesn't need to be done again. I want to be 'inclusive' of questions like this but I do wonder if it's possible to find an answer, given the mess.

Comment: I think it's hard to read that question now. It's a very important topic for a couple website owners because it's causing problems to host the website or at least result in higher monthly costs (in my case ~$5.000)

Comment: @user114293 it *is* hard to read that question now, yes. Part of the problem, with all respect, is that it's always been hard to read the question because essentially you posted a comment about something you'd seen in your logs and essentially asked "has anyone else seen this". Not trying to be funny here but that's not a great start for a question. We all understand that this is an important issue which is why we're trying to protect the question and help it fit into our structure rather than just close it.

Comment: @DJPon3 With no respect and I'm trying to be funny :) I agree the original question was quite open and didn't expect a single answer. I just didn't know that serverfault has a problem with that. I now changed my question accordingly.

Comment: @serverfault: I'm pretty sure your domains get hit by this bot quite heavily. I'm sure you have an interest to solve that issue as well :)

Comment: Why don't we get rid of that "question" and if someone thinks it's important enough they can post a new question, properly worded *as* a question this time.